# Solrj Select All

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having issues selecting everything in my 25 document Solr (3.6) index via Solrj (running Tomcat).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException { 

        SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
        ModifiableSolrParams parameters = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        parameters.set("?q", "*:*");
        parameters.set("wt", "json");

        QueryResponse response = solr.query(parameters);
            System.out.println(response); 
    }
```

The result I get is:

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=0,params={?q=*:*,wt=javabin,version=2}},response={numFound=0,start=0,docs=[]}}
```

Also, If I take the "?" out of `parameters.set("?q", "*:*");`I have to terminate the compilation or else it times out. The same happens if I replace the

```
"*:*"
```

with just

```
"*"
```

Also, I have tried `parameters.set("qt", "/select");`to no avail.

How do you select all and actually get results through Solrj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this works but after failing on a hundred ideas, this one took:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException { 

        SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
        ModifiableSolrParams parameters = new ModifiableSolrParams();
          parameters.set("q", "*:*"); //query everything thanks to user1452132!
          parameters.set("facet", true);//without this I cant select all
          parameters.set("fl", "id");//send back just the id values
          parameters.set("wt", "json");//Id like this in json format please

        QueryResponse response = solr.query(parameters);
            System.out.println(response); 
    }
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using "q" as the parameter and the following is the right syntax.

```
parameters.set("?q", "*:*");
```

The reason why it returns with "?q" is that there is no query to run, so it returns fast.

First, please test through the browser.  You can also set the number of rows to return, so that you are not returning a large result set.

```
parameters.set("rows", 5);
```

Once solr query returns, you have to paginate through the results.  If you had a large collection you wont be able to retrieve all of them in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I run q=*:* in the browser everything comes up fine. However when I run it with Solrj I get timed out in eclipse and need to Terminate. Is there somewhere I can check in my schema or solrconfig xml's (or anywhere else) to see why?

Comment: If you can run your process outside eclipse, you can send it a ctl+Break or kill -3 to get thread dump.  That will tell you what it is doing when it is "hanging".  That will give you clues.

Comment: Not directly related but why don't you use the `SolrQuery` class which extends `ModifiableSolrParams`? It's really handy to pass parameters to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to also specify your core whenever you are referring to  SolrServer object, i.e., write

```
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1");
```

where collection1 is the name of the core that you want to use.